# About billable hours/day and time waiting for clients reply

Tags: time-management, billable-hours

I've set myself 6 daily billable hours, with an X value per hour. However, on most days, I only work 2-3 hours and spend the rest of my time (5-6 hours) waiting for client responses.

Should I reduce my billable hours to 3-4? That would significantly increase my hourly value, but I'm not sure what to do with that increase.

There is a relevant answer to my question [here](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/7729/do-you-bill-for-time-waiting-for-client-to-respond-within-a-single-shift-day), but the accepted answer basically says that you can do other tasks while waiting; I, on the other hand, cannot. When I have to multitask on multiple projects at the same time I make a lot of mistakes, and I mean it. My service quality significantly deteriorates when doing so.

So, if you have any suggestions or insights that could help me bill my work hours more accurately while also focusing on no more than one project, it would be greatly appreciated. If what I'm looking for is the holy grail, I'm open to other ideas as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real question is: are you working as an "Employee Equivalent" or are you running a business?

When you state that you "set myself 6 daily billable hours", that sounds like you consider yourself equivalent to an employee. An employee works 6 hours and uses 2 hours for email and other overhead for that business.

The problem is that an "employee equivalent" needs a sales organization to get work for that person. That sales organization will take a huge chunk out of the billable rate.

Many years ago, I saw the following financial model for a business. The percentages fit also how a single person business might need to allocate their time.

Of every dollar that comes in:

- 20% goes to taxes and profit
- 25% goes to sales and marketing
- 15% goes to administration and overhead
- 40% goes to actually building the product or doing the work

This has major implications for pricing. This is why a business charges so much over what it costs to actually do the work. I spend a lot of time on marketing.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I like that it's in percentages because that means values will vary depending on how many daily hours you want to commit to your business. But I'm a bit confused about considering myself an employee or a business. I set myself a certain daily amount, but I was thinking more something like "That's how many hours I want to spend daily on my self-employed business." Is that an improper mindset?

Comment: I have heard many business owners say that they are "working on their business". I can spend 8 hours a day on the business, but perhaps have only 3-4 hours billable. The rest of the time is on marketing, accounting, planning, and other overhead. "The person who does your marketing sets your rate and determines your income."

Comment: "The person who does your marketing sets your rate and determines your income." How so? Is it a saying or is it something that marketers actually do? Shouldn't that be a thing for accountants?

Comment: Most times, it is not a conscious decision. It is a consequence of their actions. For example, I read about a consultant who charged $1,000/hr. He spent 80% of his time on marketing his services. When someone suggested that he could cut back the marketing to get more billable time, his response was that it was because he spent 80% of his time on marketing that he was able to get the billable time at that rate.

Comment: Well, yeah. The more billable time you cut, the more you'll have to raise your rates. Secondly, could you expand on your answer? What do you mean when you mention "...on taxes and profit", "...to sales and marketing" and the other two? I'm trying to put into action what I would do with that 20% on taxes and profit, for example. I'm new to the business side of independent work, so it's kind of ambiguous for me.

Comment: I suggest thinking the other way: the more time spent on marketing, the more you are able to raise your rate and get customers who will pay that. First commit to doing the marketing and getting the customers. Then, raise your rate when you have enough customers.

Comment: As a single businessperson, you might want to think of vacation time instead of profit. It is possible to adjust how you spend so that the profit reported to tax authorities is small to minimize how much tax you pay. But planning on having the "fruits of your labor" is very important. It is too easy to spend all your time including holidays on the business. Overhead includes the rent on office space. Administration includes all the time spent dealing with getting equipment, filling out government forms, insurance, etc.

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep in mind your insights :)